# NoSQL replication with lots of subscribers

Tags: nosql, replication

Is there a NoSQL implementation (prefer C/C++/Erlang implementations) which can handle lots of read only subscribers (up to 200)?

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 2):

200 is pretty small. Any implementation should handle this.